# how to implement ads on 2 view controllers

Tags: singleton, admob, viewcontroller, banner, didfailwitherror

I want the iAd/AdMob mediation banner to NOT be affected by what ViewController I'm in. Currently. When I change View Controllers didFailToReceiveAdWithError is called and the AdMob banner in that method appears when I change ViewControllers. I use 2 ViewControllers for my entire app, so is there a way to make the ads NOT be affected by the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me like you placed an ad on each view controller. When you transition between view controllers a new ad is called. You should instead use a singular ad banner. That way no matter what view controller you're on there will always be 1 ad banner running across both screens.

Comment: Since you're the only one that answered and i've heard of single ad banner view controller but i wasn't sure if it's right for me, i guess i'll try to implement it. Thanks.